# Why is this counting down after reaching the target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I wanted to have a counter that only activates when actually on the screen. I've managed to mangle this together from other examples I've found.

HTML:

```
<div>Scroll Down</div>
<span class="count">200</span>
```

CSS:

```
div {
   height:800px;
   background:red;
}
h1 {
   display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
        hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT - wH), wS);
    if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
        $('.count').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 4000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function(now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

DEMO:

https://jsfiddle.net/76d57vjL/

The problem is, it reaches 200 and then counts back down to 0 but I want it to just stay at 200. I can't seem to figure out whats actually causing it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you were creating more than 1 animation, so going back to 1 after starting the count, i fixed it with a flag, but probably you could make something with the heights to check that out.

Here's the fix with the flag: https://jsfiddle.net/uc0av8fh/

```
var flag = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('#scroll-to');
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT-wH) , wS);
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
    $('.count').each(function () {
      if(!flag) return;
      //console.log();
      flag = false;
      $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
          duration: 4000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function (now) {
              $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
              return 1;
          }
      });
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Why doesn't it work here though?
https://jsfiddle.net/ys5x3du0/

Comment: you need to add the id scroll-to to the div. I added in my example because i thought your real coide had it.